# What is the proper way to get full stack trace of classes/methods that runs on a page?

Tags: magento2, php, xdebug

I have my dev environment with VSCode, Docker, WSL and Xdebug enabled and I can set breakpoints to evaluate all objects that I want on runtime, but sometimes I need to just obtain which classes are called on certain things on the frontend, for instance, the controller class of the search suggestions when you type any search term on the search bar but not pressing Enter...

Is that possible? I think it's possible setting Xdebug in profile mode and also the Xdebug helper extension on Chrome in profile too but after do that, it just don't trace anything...

Any ideas? or is there anything that I'm missing?

Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to understand your need but you can use the logger to debug directly from a class.

Like this :

```
class xxxx {
      protected \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger;

          public function __construct(
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger
    ) {
        $this->_logger = $logger;
    }
}
```

and in your code/function

```
        $this->_logger->info('What i need to log');
```

you can pass variable but not an object

You can see this line in system.log

Comment: In fact, using loggers to just debug classes is a sloppy way. Its better to use Xdebug with your IDE listening to accelerate your development without need to add logger lines everywhere.